Adjusting the fundamental interactions to create abnormally hard structures
The Scientocratic Hivemind has the ability to engulf matter in a magic field. Within this, they can strengthen or weaken the fundamental forces that governs each atom. They can selectively choose which specific atoms or force to adjust. It can pick how long the changes can last.
I intend it to use this ability for construction purposes like creating massive structures that can endure impacts more than its composition can naturally handle.
What force/s (e.g. gravity, electromagnetism, weak/strong nuclear force, etc.) should be used to achieve this strengthening?

Are gases supposed to be matter in this case?

@Antares As long as it has atoms

To whomever voted to close as opinion-based... that's a VTC reason I use very sparingly on Worlbuilding because 99.999% of all questions asked here are fundamentally opinion-based. My personal measure is whether or not the [help/dont-ask] "all answers have equal value" prohibition has been triggered. I don't believe this question has that problem. Keep in mind... imaginary worlds... we sometimes use science to rationalize worldbuilding rules. We don't hold worldbuilding rules to the strictures of known science. (I'm assuming that's the reason you voted that way.)

Just as a suggestion. Do you really need to explain it any further? Stories can definitely become better with some detail from reality, even with magic. But always consider if you actually need it. 'They use magic to increase molecular bonds' is probably enough for the reader, while 'they use magic to increase the covalent bond with 0.008MeV and the ionic bonds by a factor of 1.2' can lead to reader fatigue, as well as writing yourself into a corner if something could/couldn't break it while you want to story wise.

I don't think you mean hardness. Generally hardness is not a good measure of how good a building material is, that would be toughness. Many hard things are also exceptionally brittle. Diamond is one of the hardest things known but you could snap a 2 inch rod of diamond in half with your bare hands. Nor is hardness a good measure of resistance to impact, you can smash a diamond inot powder with a normal hammer, but a steel ball bearing of the same size will barely notice the impact.

Turn up the gravity
Gravity is about forty orders of magnitude weaker than the rest of the fundamental forces, to the point that it can basically be ignored in most molecular and atomic physics problems.  If you increased the force of gravity in a volume by a factor of about $10^{37}$, you would introduce a new universal attraction that was similar in strength to the electromagnetic force that binds molecules together, but still 100× smaller than the strong nuclear force.  Hopefully there is a sweet spot in there where you fundamentally change chemistry and metallurgy, but don't do too much damage to particle physics and turn all your materials into fusion bombs.
A material in this hyper-gravity environment would naturally settle into a much denser, more compact state with much stronger crystal bonds, faster sound propagation and a lower internal temperature.  Everything would behave a bit strangely as a result, but not too outlandishly.  The real magic comes when you move materials into or out of this space.
When you move a material out of the field, it will expand rapidly back to its normal density, probably explosively.  It gains a large amount of thermal energy by having the negative potential energy of its enhanced gravitational attraction 'cancelled' when it passes into regular space.  When passing objects the other way - like a cannonball fired at your magic wall - the reverse happens: the material 'recalibrates' to a much lower effective temperature and wants to collapse into a denser state, but this takes time, and in the meantime the material behaves as if it is actually an artificially-contained ball of gaseous material.  The faster you fire your projectile, the less time it has to condense into a proper impactor again and so the less effective it would be.  As such, a gravity field would be especially effective at protecting materials from impacts.

There is no single force to rule them all.
Molecular forces
Atoms and their molecule bonds they can form with others incorporate various forces that hold them together. They change with environmental conditions like pressure, gravity etc., by material composition like dipol-bonding in water or magnetic bonding in cobalt, nickel, iron or hydrogen-bonding if hydrogen is involved, and many more.

Environmental conditions: pressure, gravity, (more?)
Material properties: dipol-bonding, hydrogen-bonding, (electro-)magnetic bonding, metallic bonding, electron bonding, etc.
Phase: solid, liquid, gaseous, plasma

Roughly speaking you can categorize those forces in inter-molecular (between  molecules) and intra-molecular (inside molecules).
Applying to the scenario
The picture should be clear that if magic is thought of to strengthen only one of those forces, that is a tough call, because the forces to be considered vary with so many parameters and every material.
The best option would be to resort to the environmental conditions. But those also have their shortcomings:

Gravity might be an option, because of its universality, but it also depends upon the magic field's properties. Does it act as a barrier to those forces or does it affect matter outside of the field as well. If it does, this has some maybe unwanted implications as it alters attractive forces in the vicinity and can, in an extreme case, end up creating a black hole.

Increasing the pressure inside the magic field can have extreme effects on the material as well. With higher pressure phases change between solid-liquid (melting-freezing), solid-gaseous (sublimation-deposition), liquid-gaseous (vaporization-condensation) or gas-plasma (ionization-recombination) can occur along changes in temperature and depending on the material.


Conclusion
It does not seem to be plausible to explain the effect of the magic field with the strengthening of one specific force. The magic effect has to apply to everything inside the magic field depending on what matter is inside this field.
As a consequence, instead of designating an existing force to explain the strengthening effect, adding one magic force that applies to any matter would probably be the best way to go in terms of plausibility and agreement with physics/chemistry.
